# Sharing singleton flux stores in React

Tags: reactjs-flux

So the general gist I've got with flux is that stores should always be a singleton. In my example I have the following :

A people store which controls the CRUD operations of people, as well as search / filtering.

I now have 2 components which show at the same time that make use of this filtering, my issue at the moment is with the current implementation they would be filtering on both components due to their shared store.

My current idea for solutions are:

1. Have filtering controlled in controller components
2. Have 2 separate stores that cover each of their domains and have filtering functionality in a shared util

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first solution sounds ok to me.

Nonetheless you can also implement a buffer, made of a hashtable in order to separate temporary filtering results, as if they were sessions.

Pros:
You can alter the shared data and if several components are looking to the same data, every change will be reflected in all those components.

Cons:
There will be a lot of change events and you will need to check if the store change event is important to your component before change its state in order to prevent unnecessary render calls.